# Class is not key value coding-compliant for the key error without any wrong connections

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am using Daniel Gindi's chart library and my idea is to have multiple line charts display on a ScrollView.

I have a ScrollView that is supposed to display 4 line charts. They will be 4 separate graphs i.e they will not be plotted on the same axes (although they share the same x-axis values). My app crashes when I change to this view due to SIGABRT error.

First I tried making individual functions for each of the graphs but I realised you cannot do that due to the use of LineChartEntry in the function, they have to be separate instances for the different graphs. So I tried writing a general function as seen below.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class sparkTrendController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller1TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller2TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller3TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller4TrendSpark: LineChartView!


    var numberOfSparksChiller1: [Double] = [5,8,6,4,2,1,2,1,1,0]

    var numberOfSparksChiller2: [Double] = [10,13,8,7,8,7,5,4,2,1]

    var numberOfSparksChiller3: [Double] = [15,13,8,2,2,7,5,5,6,1]

    var numberOfSparksChiller4: [Double] = [12,3,5,7,3,7,5,4,7,1]

    var daysNumbered: [Double] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

    var lineChartEntry1 = [ChartDataEntry]()

    var lineChartEntry2 = [ChartDataEntry]()

    var lineChartEntry3 = [ChartDataEntry]()

    var lineChartEntry4 = [ChartDataEntry]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Trends of Sparks"
        updateGraph(daysNumbered: daysNumbered, numberOfSparks: numberOfSparksChiller1, label: "Chiller 1", chiller: chiller1TrendSpark)
        updateGraph(daysNumbered: daysNumbered, numberOfSparks: numberOfSparksChiller2, label: "Chiller 2", chiller: chiller2TrendSpark)
        updateGraph(daysNumbered: daysNumbered, numberOfSparks: numberOfSparksChiller3, label: "Chiller 3", chiller: chiller3TrendSpark)
        updateGraph(daysNumbered: daysNumbered, numberOfSparks: numberOfSparksChiller4, label: "Chiller 4", chiller: chiller4TrendSpark)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func updateGraph(daysNumbered: [Double], numberOfSparks: [Double], label: String, chiller: LineChartView) {
        var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0..<daysNumbered.count {
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: daysNumbered[i], y: numberOfSparks[i])
            if chiller == chiller1TrendSpark {
                lineChartEntry = lineChartEntry1
            }
            if chiller == chiller2TrendSpark {
                lineChartEntry = lineChartEntry2
            }
            if chiller == chiller3TrendSpark {
                lineChartEntry = lineChartEntry3
            }
            if chiller == chiller4TrendSpark {
                lineChartEntry = lineChartEntry4
            }
            lineChartEntry.append(value)
            //LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry, label: label)
            LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry, label: label).colors = [NSUIColor.red]
            let data = LineChartData()
            data.addDataSet(LineChartDataSet(entries: lineChartEntry, label: label))
            chiller.data = data
            chiller.chartDescription?.text = "Number Of Sparks"
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I tried rewriting the code like this and it still has the same error.

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class sparkTrendController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller1TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller2TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller3TrendSpark: LineChartView!

    @IBOutlet weak var chiller4TrendSpark: LineChartView!


    var numberOfSparksChiller1: [Double] = [5,8,6,4,2,1,2,1,1,0]

    var numberOfSparksChiller2: [Double] = [10,13,8,7,8,7,5,4,2,1]

    var numberOfSparksChiller3: [Double] = [15,13,8,2,2,7,5,5,6,1]

    var numberOfSparksChiller4: [Double] = [12,3,5,7,3,7,5,4,7,1]

    var daysNumbered: [Double] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Trends of Sparks"

        customizeChart(dataPoints: numberOfSparksChiller1, values: daysNumbered, lineChartView: chiller1TrendSpark, label: "Chiller 1 Sparks")
        customizeChart(dataPoints: numberOfSparksChiller2, values: daysNumbered, lineChartView: chiller2TrendSpark, label: "Chiller 2 Sparks")
        customizeChart(dataPoints: numberOfSparksChiller3, values: daysNumbered, lineChartView: chiller3TrendSpark, label: "Chiller 3 Sparks")
        customizeChart(dataPoints: numberOfSparksChiller4, values: daysNumbered, lineChartView: chiller4TrendSpark, label: "Chiller 4 Sparks")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func customizeChart (dataPoints: [Double
        ], values: [Double], lineChartView: LineChartView, label: String) {

        //1) set ChartDataEntry
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let entries = ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: dataPoints[i])
            //let dataEntry = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: label)
            dataEntries.append(entries)
        }
        //2) set ChartDataSet
        let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: label)

        //3) set ChartData
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        //4) assign it to chart's data
        lineChartView.data = lineChartData

    }


}
```

For the second code, this is the error at the debug area.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Github repo: https://github.com/danialaqil/TFAApp/tree/master/AlarmChartsApp. The problematic code is the sparkTrendController.swift file

Comment: Your code have bug! in line `lineChartEntry = lineChartEntry1`, `lineChartEntry1` is empty. Where did you fill `lineChartEntry1`?

Comment: That is a good point. I tried putting the values in lineChartEntry.append(value).

Comment: I added my new code, I thought I addressed the issues but the app still crashes. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where define `lineChartView`? Can you send the exact text to the crashes?

Comment: I have added the crashes, thank you so much for helping me

Comment: Check your `chiller1TrendSpark` connection from storyboard to viewcontroller class!

Comment: I have checked and it is identical to the rest of the connections to the viewcontroller class. I tried removing chiller1TrendSpark and it still did not work, as now the code crashes mentioning chiller2TrendSpark instead. I am doing it in a scroll view, inside a content view, then inside a viewcontroller. There are no connections between them. Could this be the issue?

Comment: If it helps, the github repo for my project is https://github.com/danialaqil/TFAApp/tree/master/AlarmChartsApp and the relevant file is the SparkTrendController.swift